# Subscription Renewal Related

Tags: stripe-payments

I was using your stripe payment gateway for a while then one day one thing came to my mind. I would like to explain it with an example.

Suppose I am a customer and subscribed to some app. So you will deduct that monthly charges every month. Now what happens is my card got empty and the subscription renewal date is near.  As I was not having enough money in my card I got logged out from the app and stripe kept trying my  card. Then to re-login to app I was asked to enter the card details again. Now this time I used another card and got logged in successfully as a new user on the app (as my status was marked as 'not renewed' in the database).

So now my questions are:

1. What will happen if I put some money in my previous card?
2. Will I get charged twice every month?
3. How can handle this equation?
4. Have you understood my point of view?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be a programming problem, but more of a financial/payment question.

Answer (score 0):

With Stripe, users (merchants) can set a retry schedule for recurring payments in their account settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/recurring. There can be up to 3 retries after the initial attempt, each retry separated by 1 to 7 days from the previous one.

If all payment attempts fail, users can choose the final fate of the subscription:

- cancel it automatically
- mark it as unpaid
- leave it as-is

If you [update a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer) with a new payment source, for each of the customer's current subscriptions, if the subscription is in the `past_due` state, then the latest unpaid, unclosed invoice for the subscription will be retried.